# How to react when client explains "it will be used for illegal activities"?

Tags: legal, freelancing

Scenario:

Freelancer (from Norway if that's relevant) is approached by Mr. X (from unknown origin, if that's relevant) about creating SoftwareX, they agree on the scope and price. Mr. X does a small prepayment, and shortly after development starts, Mr. X casually explains that SoftwareX will be used for illegal activities.

How should the freelancer react to that? Just ignore it and continue development? Cancel the whole deal (if so, how?)? Something else?

Comment: Given that you are a freelancer, this is best answered on [Freelance SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com).  But my gut feeling is contracts and lawyers.

Comment: what illegal activities? It's just software. Even if it's  for a missile guidance system that wouldn't be lllegal

Comment: @Kilisi So you'd be happy to write code for me that is going to be used to scam innocent people out of their life's savings by tricking them into handing over their bank account details?

Comment: @PeterM I'm not a dev, I'm an engineer, so that software wouldn't work very well and no one would be fooled. But as an engineer I build to spec and get paid. I wouldn't build a bomb though.

Comment: @Kilisi Marcus Hutchins got in a lot of trouble for creating malware on a contract basis, even as he may not have been 100% willing, so please don't advise that it's "just software". There can be serious consequences for doing so.

Comment: Are you willing to take the risk and being paid accordingly?

Comment: Here in the US, this is known as aiding and abetting. Selling someone a product knowing they’re going to use it to commit a crime basically makes you a co-conspirator. I don’t know what the law is in Norway but I can only imagine that helping someone break the law is considered a crime just about anywhere.

Comment: It really depends on how criminal it is. Writing a page that you know is for scam is a bad idea, but building a Taxi ordering website that doesn't 100% comply with local regulations of all markets, might be a different story.

Comment: Can you say more about what  the illegal activities are? This may depend on whether you can also be prosecuted. I don't agree with @JoeStrazzere's claim that the chances to get money are neccessarily slim. Facebook also did illegal stuff (and many companies do if the money they obtain is higher than the penality) but I wouldn't say they never pay their stuff.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? It seems on topic to me.

Comment: Please clarify "illegal". There are many options, from obvious (manufacturing a bomb without any kind of license) to grey areas like manufacturing a steak knife for a guy you know wants to murder his wife to the legally complicated areas like writing accounting software for a shop selling weed, something that is legal where they do it, but illegal where you live and work. I don't think there is a one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: An illegal activity could also be "an employer who does not do anything against it when the employers work overtime", something many chefs on Workplace SE do and something like all universities in Academia SE. This is horrible for sure, but not so bad as  people here do (and I wouldn't call it a risk to sell those people software in terms of payment as in @Studoku 's comment). We need more clarification, OP!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Just because someone engages in _some_ criminal activities doesn't mean that they will commit any crime they can think of, like not paying OP. If anything, their illegal intentions (and having revealed them to OP) gives OP leverage to not be shafted by their client. Note that I'm not saying that OP should happily work for them, but the reason to not do so isn't "because he won't pay me". In suggesting so, you indirectly suggest that were OP's questionable client to guarantee payment (e.g. by paying upfront), the issue would be resolved - which it wouldn't be.

Comment: Knowingly support someone in committing a crime is also a crime in most places. I would talk to a lawyer!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You walk away as quickly as possible and alert the authorities if it's bad stuff.

You can potentially try to keep some pre-payment for hours already worked, but it's much safer and more ethical to just return it and keep your nose clean.

Comment: The last thing you want to do is to "owe" (rightfully or not) money to criminal organizations. This isn't a petty street thug you're dealing with. Refund, walk away.

Comment: @Nelson: There is nothing said about "criminial organisation". Facebook also uses software for "illegal activities" (storing more user data then allowed by law) yet I wouldn't call it a criminal organisation (sounds like mafia).

Comment: The main point is not whether it is really a big time criminal organization or not. The main issue is this person engaging in illegal activity is organized enough to actually go through a round of work proposal without sounding like a complete moron. This is a massive red flag. This criminal is more organized than some businesses, and you want to get away from this guy ASAP.

Comment: I think the point is more that *you don't know, and don't want to know* whether this person is part of organised crime or not.

Comment: @Nelson: Yet, Facebook does not sound like an organisation who does not pays its debts or will kill you or threaten your family or whatever. I don't think it's so absurd to owe them money.

Comment: Do you really think the worst case scenario is OP got freelance work from Facebook? There are no details as to what "illegal" really means, and OP **should simply walk away and don't try to know more**. Anything remotely close to Silk Road v1 and the OP is probably going to get killed.

Comment: @Nelson: My point is that unless the OP clarifies what exactly they mean, we cannot say the "organisation" could kill the OP/steal money etc. As another commenter said, if illegal "just" means "writing a taxi app which does not observe all rules" or similar, it's bad and they should go to the authorities (or maybe not, see Snowden) but they do not have to fear to be killed and "criminal organisation" is then not the right term. Not everybody who does an illegal thing kills people.

Comment: Short of even the hint that you can potentially keep some of the money (do not do this, they will take it back from you or someone else, speaking from experience here), this is the correct answer. Return the money, block the number and email, never ever contact them again under no circumstances. Nothing good will come from any other option.

Comment: @Nelson: The suggestion that OP is liable to get killed or even harmed when they cross anyone who has broken _any_ law, no matter how trivial or non-violent the crime may be, is astronomically exaggerated and sounds more like B-movie logic. Crime is not inherently violent, there are plenty of laws that can be broken without physically harming others. If I were to hire OP to build a website that slanders a celebrity, I'd be intending to break a law, but there's no reason to assume I would resort to murder or harm to a contractor who refused to work the commission.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone contributing here are actual criminals and speak from experience? It also really depends on which country the OP is in. As much as it is speculation, I'm going to emphasize on caution without going into details as to why, which is irrelevant.

Comment: @Nelson: I've broken laws before. Nothing shocking, but even just speeding fits the bill. I have not once considered violent retribution towards anyone who either did not help me speed, negatively commented on me speeding, or in any other way broached the topic of speeding contrary to my opinion on it. Even by your outrageous "only criminals could speak from experience" standard, your argument still falls flat.

Answer (score 12):

I see three possible cases here.

1. MrX is a stupid petty criminal who needs qualified help to enact his sordid schemes but who will never pay Freelancer more than some token amounts to keep him working.
2. MrX is a member of a well-organized crime syndicate who will recruit Freelancer deeper and deeper into aiding and abetting until he doesn't dare try to break away.
3. MrX is a government agent who will gather a little more evidence and then throw Freelancer into jail.

None of these cases involves a sustainable contract.

The *only* safe thing for Freelancer to do in any case is to cease work immediately, suspend all correspondence with MrX, and report everything to the highest police authority that will listen to him.

I don't know who you'd report to in Norway. Here in the U.S.A. I would talk to the FBI.

Comment: `stupid` sounds about right, it amazes me how people doesn't keep stuff like that on a `need-to-know` basis (as i assume the smarter ones does)

Comment: 3. is called entrapment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do the most obvious thing: Ask the client which laws they intend to break.
Then go forward from this, asking the following questions yourself (which you should also ask if the client does not do anything illegal):

(a)  What do my ethics say about the client's activity?

That something is illegal does not mean it is "bad". Indeed, there are eg dictatorships with laws prohibiting free speech, denying women's rights etc. You may have a different opinion than the law about drugs, pirating songs etc.
Note the fact that something is legal might also not imoly that you are okay with the activity. Cheating in exams may be legal, but maybe you would not feel okay in creating a "cheating-abing application". Some illegal activities are "bad, but not that bad". Yesterday, I was longer (voluntarily) at work, my boss saw it but did not say "go home now!". This was illegal for the boss, but no so bad that I would call the FBI.. Facebook collects data illegaly but nobody would call it a "criminal organisation".

(b) What happens to me if I do the activity and get caught?

I dont know the laws in Norway but I would hope "helping someone to murder" gets punished, but "helping someone to jaywalk" does not get punished. Also, it might be that in your jurisdiction the activity is not a crime (probably no set of two countries has exactly the same laws..).
Conversely, it could be that the activity is legal but you could get reprimanded if you do it (bad reputation).
Consult a lawyer, if necessary!

(c) Is the client trustworthy?

If the criminal activity involves directly money, it could be that you don't trust the client to pay you.
Of course, this could also hold for "legal clients": if they have a repuation of going fully lawyer and thus avoid payments, you could also decide that you don't trust them.

Note that I am not a subscriber of the theory presented in the comments "the client could kill you". I dom't believe that "being capable of doing any crime" implies "being capable of doing all crimes".
Nevertheless, of course, depending on your answer to the three questions, you should not only determine if you want to work with the client, but also if you want to report them.

Answer (score -1):

There is a chance Mr. X is just running his mouth to seem important.

But even so, or one of the A. I. Breveleri variations your only option is to stop communicating with Mr. X and report what you know to the authorities with solid evidence and your communication history with Mr X.